Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find 'GeneratedPluginRegistrant' in scope
I am not familiar with flutter but I am trying to deploy a flutter project. I initially got error from the awesome_notifications so I updated some packages in the pubspec.yaml file and now got an error that states
`Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find 'GeneratedPluginRegistrant' in scope
~/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:25:4
Encountered error while building for device.`
I tried to re-install pod, checked Podfile and checked the pubspec.yaml but not sure what the issue is.
**pubspec.yaml
**
name: parkinsons_app
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.0 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  json_annotation: ^4.8.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  package_info_plus: ^4.2.0
  package_info_plus_platform_interface: ^2.0.1
  gaimon: ^1.1.1+1
  survey_kit: ^0.2.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.1
  flutter_screen_lock: ^9.0.1
  intl: ^0.18.0   # To format/parse date time
  awesome_notifications: ^0.8.2
  localstorage: ^4.0.0
  http: ^1.0.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  animated_check: ^1.0.0
  animated_cross: ^1.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0 #2.0.0 4.0.0

  build_runner: ^2.4.11 #2.3.3 2.4.11
  json_serializable: ^6.6.0

  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"


flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/icon.png"
    background_color: "#hexcode"
    theme_color: "#hexcode"
  windows:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/icon.png"
    icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
  macos:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/icon.png"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # Fonts
  fonts:
    - family: DMSans-Regular
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/DMSans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/DMSans-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: DMSans-Bold
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/DMSans-Bold.ttf
        - asset: fonts/DMSans-BoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: DMSans-Medium
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/DMSans-Medium.ttf
        - asset: fonts/DMSans-MediumItalic.ttf
          style: italic

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages



  assets:
    - assets/survey_json.json
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages


**
AppDelegate.swift**
import UIKit
import Flutter


@main
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

